# Dynamically bind values to double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a table on the fly using JQuery and javascript.I am also binding methods for each row successfully however when i try bind the dblclick event it always uses the last rows values (in this case the last customer in the list):

```
            for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
                var newRow = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                newRow.attr('onmouseover', 'rowMouseOver_Popup(' + i + ');');
                newRow.attr('onmouseout', 'rowMouseOut_Popup(' + i + ');');
                newRow.attr('onclick', 'rowSelect_Popup(' + i + ');');
                //above is working fine                    

                //below (adding the dblclick) doesn't work
                newRow.dblclick(function () {
                    selectCustomer(customers[i].Cust_Code,  customers[i].Cust_Name);
                });

                newRow.appendTo(tbl);
                }
```

I have tried a few variations like below but no such luck:

```
newRow.on('dblclick', 'selectCustomer(\'' + customers[i].Cust_Code + '\'' + ',' + '\'' + customers[i].Cust_Name + '\');');

newRow.attr('dblclick', 'selectCustomer(' + customers[i].Cust_Code + '\'' + ',' + '\'' + customers[i].Cust_Name + '\');');
```

I guess it is the scope or context of the function call which I don't understand , if you could add a link to your answer so I could learn more about the problem/solution I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: works fine for me, **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/JWLq8/)** .Check your console for errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you reset handler on each i, so listener has last i as an argument at the end of cycle.

Use ondblclick, since you already use inline event handlers:

```
var code = customers[i].Cust_Code,
    name = customers[i].Cust_Name;
newRow.attr('ondblclick', 'selectCustomer(' + code + ','  +  name + ')');
```

In your case you can use delegate listener, using this:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < customers.length; i++) {
            var newRow = $("<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
            newRow.attr('index', i);
            newRow.appendTo(tbl);
 }
```

Now set listeners with jquery:

```
 $('tr[index]').on('click',rowSelect_Popup($(this).attr('index')))
 .on('onmouseover',rowMouseOver_Popup($(this).attr('index')))
 .on('onmouseout',rowMouseOut_Popup($(this).attr('index')))
 .on('ondblclick',function() { 

 var i = $(this).attr('index'),
     code = customers[i].Cust_Code,
     name = customers[i].Cust_Name;

 selectCustomer(code,name);
 })
```

In my experience, alse it's better to use mouseenter and mouseleave events instead of mouseover and mouseout. But it's up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your time, and extra information, appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is better.

```
/**
 * In this case using on is much better.
 * check this:
 * http://api.jquery.com/on/
 */
newRow.on("dblclick", {Cust_Code: customers[i].Cust_Code,
                       Cust_Name: customers[i].Cust_Name}, function(event) {
    selectCustomer(event.data.Cust_Code,  event.data.Cust_Name);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
newRow.ondblclick=function(){ SomeJavaScriptCode };
```